# Creating opencv Mat to 2d grid

Tags: c++, opencv, path-finding, a-star

I am building a search algorithm using OpenCV Mat where I convert the Mat to gray image and then check the pixel to sign it to walkable or not walkable with their coordinate. I use vector > grid. when I try to print the nodeID from the grid the program sudden shutdown (e.g `grid.grid[10][10]->NodeID`).

```
using namespace std;
int gridZise;
class location{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

};

class Node{
public:
    int gridX;
    int gridY;
    bool walkable;
    location worldPosition;
    int NodeID;


    int gCost;
    int hCost;
    Node *parent;

    Node(bool _walkable, int _gridX, int _gridY)
        {
            walkable = _walkable;
            gridX = _gridX;
            gridY = _gridY;
            NodeID = gridY * gridZise + gridX;
        }
    Node(int _gridX, int _gridY){
        gridX = _gridX;
        gridY = _gridY;
        NodeID = gridY * gridZise + gridX;
    }

    int fCost(){
        return gCost + hCost;
    }

};

class Grid{

public:
    cv::Mat map;
    vector<vector<Node*> > grid;
    int gridx;
    int gridy;


    Grid(cv::Mat _map){
        map = _map;
        gridx = map.cols;
        gridy = map.cols;
        gridZise = map.cols;
    }

    void CreateGrid(){
        // Set up sizes. (HEIGHT x WIDTH)
          grid.resize(gridy);
          for (int i = 0; i < gridy; ++i)
            grid[i].resize(gridx);

          // build up the grid
          for(int i=0; i <gridx;i++){
              for(int j=0; j < gridy;j++){
                  int pixel_val = map.at<int>(i,j);
                  bool _walkable = false;
                  if(pixel_val > 120){//if the value of the pixel is bigger than 120 is walkable
                       _walkable = true;
                  }
                  grid[i][j]->walkable = _walkable;
                  grid[i][j]->gridX = i;
                  grid[i][j]->gridY = j;
              }
          }
    }

    void PrintGrid(){
        for(int i=0; i <gridx;i++){
            for(int j=0; j < gridy;j++){
                cout << grid[i][j]->NodeID <<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    vector<Node> GetNeighbours(Node node)
        {
            vector<Node> neighbours;

            for (int x = -1; x <=1; x++)
            {
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
                {
                    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
                        continue;

                    int checkX = node.gridX + x;
                    int checkY = node.gridY + y;

                    if(checkX >=0 && checkX < gridx && checkY >=0 && checkY < gridy)
                    {
                        Node neighbour(checkX,checkY);
                        neighbours.push_back(neighbour);
                    }
                }
            }
            return neighbours;
        }

    Node nodeFromLocation(location _node){
        Node currentNode = *grid[_node.x][_node.y];
        return currentNode;
    }

};


using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    cv::Mat img;
    img = imread("C:\\Users\\abdulla\\Pictures\\maze.jpg");

    if(img.empty()){
        cout<<"image not load "<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    imshow("image",img);
    waitKey();
    Grid grid(img);

    grid.PrintGrid();

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Gray images are CV_8UC, so you need to read each pixel with uchar, `uchar pixel_val = map.at<uchar>(i,j);` . Also you can load the image with `img = imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE )`, so you don't have to convert it to gray again.

Comment: Hi @Tony J, thank you for your reply. I did use uchar instead the int. The problem is start when I try to enter the value of the node in the grid. `grid.grid[10][10].NodeID`

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of `using namespace std;`. While it may look convenient, you are setting yourself up for some nasty surprises (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) question).

The constructor of `Grid` uses the default constructor of `Grid::grid`, which creates an empty vector.

In `PrintGrid` you get undefined behaviour.

```
grid; // ok, grid is a member of Grid
grid[0]; // Returns a reference. No bounds checking is performed.
grid[0][0]; // undefined behaviour. grid[0] is outside of bounds.
```

That there is a method `CreateGrid` is not relevant here, because you never call it. But let's assume that you had called it. Then PrintGrid would work like this:

```
grid; // ok, grid is a member of Grid
grid[0]; // ok
grid[0][0]; // ok, return a pointer to a Node. Which you never initialized.
grid[0][0]->NodeID; // Undefined behaviour. You're trying to access a random memory location.
```

Do you really need to store the Nodes as pointers? You could as well use `vector<vector<Node>>`. That way, someone (`std::vector<...`) would be responsible for allocating and deleting the nodes. You can still use use pointers to point at the parents, that's fine as long as the pointers are used as a reference and not as ownership.

If you do need to store pointers, [make use of smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one%20%22make%20use%20of%20smart%20pointers%22.). That way, somebody would be responsible for deleting the nodes.

Finally, the class `Grid` is responsible for maintaining proper state. Always. So the constructor should already do what `CreateGrid` does. The problem is that you must not call `CreateGrid` from the constructor, because then you would be calling a method of an object who's lifetime has not yet started (someone correct me if I'm wrong on that one).
If you want to keep it as a seperate function you could make `CreateGrid` static:

```
class Grid {
    Grid(cv::Mat _map):
           map(_map),
           gridx(_map.cols),
           gridy(_map.cols),
           gridZise(_map.cols),
    {
        GreateGrid(grid, map, gridx, gridy);
    }

//...
    static void CreateGrid(std::vector<std::vector<Node>> & grid, cv::Mat map, int gridx, int grid y) {
    //...
    }
//...
};
```

Comment: Thank you @mars, it was very useful your advice. I re-organized my code as you said. However, the reason I use Node as point because when I use it without pointer I get this error `error: no matching function for call to  'Node::Node()'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); } ` which is not even in my my code file.

Comment: That problem can be solved. The compiler complains that it cannot default-construct Node, but it has to if you resize the vector. Whenever you create any custom constructor c++ doesn't provide automatically generated ones. Possible solutions are: 1) use reserve and push_back, 2) specify a value of Node to use during resize (e.g. `.resize(10, Node(false, 0, 0));`), 3) prove a default constructor for `Node`. Either provided by yourself `Node(): walkable(false) {}` or use the auto generated one `Node() = default;`. The same goes for the copy constructor `Node(const & Node)` if you also need that.

Comment: Thank you @mars, that solved my problem. I manage to run smoothly without any error and I manage to run it without pointer which makes the progress easier. Thank you again